# Why Android mobile is not running my application?

Tags: android

I am trying to run a simple program `hello world` in my android mobile.
but the application stops unexpectedly.
the `apk` file is installing easily but it is not running.
I do not understand why this happens

helloWorld.java

package com.hellos;

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {    
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
 @Override    
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);    
 } 
 }
```

Comment: it runs sometimes on eclipse ide successfully and sometimes show the emulator-5554 cancelling error

Comment: Need a lot more information to be able to do more than just guess. What happens when you try to run it? Are you launching it from Eclipse? Real device or emulator? Any error messages?

Comment: when i put the apk file in mobile phone. installing is ok but when i run it it stops and show a dialog box that the application stops unexpectedly. please try later. etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the [Hello World Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

If you already are and have followed it correctly (emulator installed etc) then everything should be working.

I know this may sound odd, but if you are sure all was done right try copy and pasting your code into a new project and try launching it again. (Others have done this here on SO and it has worked.)

I have had errors like this in other things, and its usually something that the phone/emulator does not like for some reason (when I think everything should work). Try to dumb down (This will behard since its hello world) your xml etc, and see if you can get it to run.

Your code should look as follows

```
package com.example.helloandroid;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {   
/** Called when the activity is first created. */   
@Override   

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
TextView tv = new TextView(this);       
tv.setText("Hello, Android");       
setContentView(tv);   }
}
```

Comment: i had followed it and copied it exactly

Comment: package com.hellos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}

Comment: Post your code/XML in your question? If you are following the tutorial your code is not what they have.